# Does Visual Studio 2015 support git config diff.algorithm?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

In general, the merge conflict tool in Visual Studio 2015 is quite good. But sometimes it gets confused and reports conflicts from seemingly hunks. Also it gets regularly confused about whitespace and tabs.

Would adjusting these configurations do anything? Or does visual studio have it's own algorithm?
`core.whitespace`
`diff.algorithm`

We are an all-windows team.